# Pesquisa a partir de formulário

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um formulário com todos os distritos de portugal. Quando eu seleciono uma cidade eu faço a pesquisa através do método `post`, recebo o `value` da cidade e a pesquisa mostra tudo que existe com o campo cidade. Até aqui tudo bem.
Mas quando o `value` da cidade é igual a TODAS ou (all), como eu posso dizer na query que o utilizador quer ver todas as cidades?

Recebendo os valores do formulario:

```
$localidade=$_REQUEST['localidade'];
$genero=$_REQUEST['genero'];
$idade_1=$_REQUEST['age-min'];
$idade_2=$_REQUEST['age-max'];
```

Consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT  u.id, u.username, u.genero, u.idade, u.local, u.descricao,   u.status,u.last_login, u.photo_p_id, p.location 

FROM user AS u 

LEFT JOIN photos AS p

ON u.photo_p_id=p.id 
WHERE local='$localidade' AND genero ='$genero' AND idade BETWEEN '$idade_1' and '$idade_2'


LIMIT 5;
";
```

O que acham da minha solução?

Recebendo os valores do formulário:

```
$consulta="local='$localidade' AND";
}else{$consulta="";}
$genero=$_REQUEST['genero'];
$idade_1=$_REQUEST['age-min'];
$idade_2=$_REQUEST['age-max'];
```

Consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT  u.id, u.username, u.genero, u.idade, u.local, u.descricao,  u.status,u.last_login, u.photo_p_id, p.location 

FROM user AS u 

LEFT JOIN photos AS p

ON u.photo_p_id=p.id 
WHERE $consulta genero ='$genero' AND idade BETWEEN '$idade_1' and '$idade_2'


LIMIT 5;
";
```

Comment: Elimine a parte `local='$localidade' AND` da cláusula WHERE

Comment: Ou crie 2 querys, uma para quando for filtrar cidades e outra pra trazer todas.

Comment: o que acham da solução que arranjei?

Comment: Se funcionar, parece-me oK!. Não percebo nada de php! :(

Comment: Nesse código, o primeiro bloco, é onde eu pego os valores da `input` dos campos do formulário.  No segundo bloco é onde eu faço a consulta à base de dados de acordo com os valores que peguei do formulário